# Hacer comboBox con mongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, select, combobox

llevo un tiempo intentado saber cómo hacer un comboBox o select multiple utilizando mongoDB desde PHP, suelo trabajar en MYSQL y es mi primera vez con mongoDB, en MYSQL el código para realizar un comboBox sería parecido al siguiente:

```
$cnx = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","mybd");

<form  method="POST">
    
        <select name="users">
        
    
        <?php
        
            $usr="select * from users";
            $result=mysqli_query($cnx, $usr);

                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                    $id=$row['id'];
                    $name=$row['name'];
                    $surname=$row['surname'];
                    $phone=$row['phone'];
                    $email=$row['email'];

                    ?>

                    <option value="<?php echo $id;?>"><?php echo $name.
                     " ".$surname." ".$phone." ".$email; ?></option>

                    <?php
                }

                     ?>

            </select>
```

Pero ni idea de cómo hacerlo para mongoDB.. gracias de antemano
**Saludos**